# How to pretty-format code (auto-insert newlines, indent, etc)?

Tags: indentation, spacemacs

I'm using `spacemacs` but presumably it's emacs knowledge that's required here.

I have a JSON file with a single long line, let's say this JSON from json.org/example:

```js
{"menu": {"id": "file", "value": "File", "popup": {"menuitem": [{"value": "New", "onclick": "CreateNewDoc()"}, {"value": "Open", "onclick": "OpenDoc()"}, {"value": "Close", "onclick": "CloseDoc()"}]}}}
```

I would like emacs to reindent this, which means to me not change the leftmost character of line to the proper indentation level, but break the line in several lines.

If I use `spacemacs/indent-region-or-buffer` (`SPC j =`) then the text is not changed at all.

How could I ask from emacs to actually break this long line and reindent to get something like this:

```js
{"menu": {
  "id": "file",
  "value": "File",
  "popup": {
    "menuitem": [
      {"value": "New", "onclick": "CreateNewDoc()"},
      {"value": "Open", "onclick": "OpenDoc()"},
      {"value": "Close", "onclick": "CloseDoc()"}
    ]
  }
}}
```

I'm not interested in a JSON-specific answer, for instance I believe that intelliJ does that for any language it supports (java, json...). I would think it's achievable for any language emacs has a major mode for, or let's say the most popular ones.

**EDIT** I discovered `M-x json-reformat-region` that `spacemacs` ships with and works, but yes, I would like that for any language and with always the same shortcut, based on the major mode...

**EDIT2** Ok so my conclusion is that it's implemented for various languages, JSON & lisp at least, presumably others, and it would be easy for yet more (XML/XHTML, go which has go-fmt and also using clang). However there's no generic function name that would do it for all the languages. There is space here to implement it in `spacemacs` layers for the various languages... I didn't find a X/HTML implementation though, which surprises me a bit.

Comment: For HTML/JS/CSS: [`web-beautiful.el`](https://github.com/yasuyk/web-beautify). This is the best I've found, but it depends on node.js.

Comment: It actually spells `web-beautify.el`

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It looks like you need the [`fill-region`](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Fill-Commands.html) function more than the indentation.

- Select that line and do `M-x fill-region`.
- Select the same, now split across multiple lines, and do `M-x indent-region`.

That will, though, not insert new lines at the exact points as shown in your example. It will simply make the line fit in the fill columns.

Comment: well, that's something. Maybe what I wanted was not achievable anyway. Maybe I'll wait a little longer in case someone has a magical solution for a smarter aggressive indentation... If nothing else comes up I'll mark this as the answer.

Comment: @EmmanuelTouzery What you want is achievable with little elisp as long as the rules for inserting the newline are consistent. In your example of formatted result, I see that you don't have a newline after `{` in `{"menu":` but you do have one after `{` in `{"id":`. I don't know JSON and so your formatted answer probably does have a pattern that I am missing. But if you can update your question with a set of rules for inserting that new line, then someone can come up with the answer you want.

Comment: I thought that would have existed for any language, including language-specific rules. For instance { on the first line for java, on next line for C# let's say, and so on.

Comment: (in other words, something like `gofmt` but for any language) -- http://gofmt.com/

Answer (score 36):

[`json.el`](https://github.com/thorstadt/json.el) package provides `json-pretty-print-buffer`.  This is what it produces for your example:

```js
{
  "menu": {
    "popup": {
      "menuitem": [
        {
          "onclick": "CreateNewDoc()",
          "value": "New"
        },
        {
          "onclick": "OpenDoc()",
          "value": "Open"
        },
        {
          "onclick": "CloseDoc()",
          "value": "Close"
        }
      ]
    },
    "value": "File",
    "id": "file"
  }
}
```

Seems pretty decent to me.

Comment: Yes in fact I saw on https://github.com/gongo/json-reformat that "From emacs 24.4, `json-pretty-print` and `json-pretty-print-buffer` (similar specifications as `json-reformat-region`) was bundled.". But I thought emacs could have a function that would work for all languages (specific for each popular major mode language), which it, as it turns out, doesn't.

Comment: this is the correct answer

Comment: In GNU ELPA's `json-mode`, this is available via `C-c C-f`

Comment: This works well if the buffer isn't screwed up already by trying M-x fill-region which can introduce new lines that makes this fail.

Answer (score 7):

According to the tip [here](http://irreal.org/blog/?p=354), you can use external command to format a region in your Json file:

```lisp
(defun json-format ()
  (interactive)
  (save-excursion
    (shell-command-on-region (region-beginning)
                             (region-end)
                             "python -m json.tool"
                             (buffer-name)
                             t)))
```

You can easily extend it to format the whole buffer:

```lisp
(defun json-format ()
  (interactive)
  (save-excursion
    (shell-command-on-region (point-min)
                             (point-max)
                             "python -m json.tool"
                             (buffer-name) t)))
```

Emacs does not have formatting tool for programming languages ([except for Lisp](https://github.com/tuhdo/semantic-refactor/blob/master/srefactor-demos/demos-elisp.org)), only indentation commands.

Comment: I discovered `M-x json-reformat-region` that `spacemacs` ships with and works, but yes, I would like that for any language and with always the same shortcut, based on the major mode... It seems that this is not supported, too bad...

Comment: To properly format a language, you need an actual language parser. Emacs has built-in language parsers for some languages, but only the built-in Lisp parser is recently used for code reformatting, as the link to the demo above. If external formatters exist, it is easy to integrate with Emacs  i.e. `clang-format`.

Answer (score 4):

For this specific scenario `M-x json-pretty-print` will prettify the highlighted lump of json.

Answer (score 2):

BTW, for major modes using SMIE as their indentation engine, there is some part of what you need for that in the form of an `auto-fill-mode` support.  I think `fill-paragraph` or `fill-region` won't do a good job, but if you put your code onto a single line, then go to the end of that line and do `M-: (smie-auto-fill)` it should give sane results (probably not perfect by a long stretch, tho).

Answer (score 1):

With emacs 26.3 you can just use the stock `json-pretty-print` function.

> json-pretty-print is an interactive and compiled function defined in
>   json.el.gz.
>
> -- Emacs 26.3 documentation

select the region and `M-x json-pretty-print`.

I've just executed this procedure taking your example as input. Here is the result:

```
{
  "menu": {
    "id": "file",
    "value": "File",
    "popup": {
      "menuitem": [
        {
          "value": "New",
          "onclick": "CreateNewDoc()"
        },
        {
          "value": "Open",
          "onclick": "OpenDoc()"
        },
        {
          "value": "Close",
          "onclick": "CloseDoc()"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I use `json-mode-beautify`

GNU Emacs 24.3.1

```
;;; json-mode.el --- Major mode for editing JSON files.

;; Copyright (C) 2011-2014 Josh Johnston

;; Author: Josh Johnston
;; URL: https://github.com/joshwnj/json-mode
;; Version: 1.6.0
```

Comment: Please elaborate. So far, this is essentially a link-only answer, so it risks being deleted. Please describe what that mode does, wrt answering the question.