# Want to Alt-Q on a long piece of text - but it has no spaces so it doesn't work

Tags: fill-paragraph

When you press Meta-Q to wrap a long blob of text, it doesn't work, probably because my text has no spaces.
my text is the result of a curl, json with no spaces.

so how do I tell emacs to add newlines at around 80 chars mark?

Comment: Maybe [that proposal to use `json-pretty-print`](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/50739/2370) helps in your specific use-case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to the beginning of the line, start a keyboard macro, advance 80 chars (`C-U 80 C-F`), add a return, finish the macro and then repeat it as many times as needed.

See [keyboard macros](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Basic-Keyboard-Macro.html#Basic-Keyboard-Macro).

Cheers,
Peter.